# Python : Increase a string

Tags: python, string, count, int

I am not really familiar with Python yet.
I have a string like `"11223300"`. Now I want to increase the last byte of that string ( from `"00"` to `"FF"`). I tried to convert the string into an integer ( `integer=int(string,16)`) and increase it, and convert it back later, but that does not work for me. Maybe one of you guys has a better idea.

```
string = "11223300"
counter = int(string, 16)

for i in range(255): 
    counter = counter + 1
    IV = hex(counter)
```

Now I want to convert the `IV` from hex into a string

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you want a hex string back? In which case, look at the [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) function.

Comment: Please include the code you have in the question, and perhaps someone could help you with it.

Comment: "integer=int(string,16)) and increase it, and convert it back later, but that does not work for me." Add your code and the error you get to your question

Comment: The code you added works exactly as expected. After the last iteration `IV` is `'0x112233ff'`

Comment: Yes right that works for me. But i need that without the "0x" and in a string. But when I convert it with string=str(IV) it does not work.

Comment: `IV` is already a string. To remove the `0x` prefix simply do `IV = IV[2:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format` to convert `int` to your hex string, which will not keep the `0x` prefix:

```
string = "11223300"
counter = int(string, 16)

for i in range(255): 
    counter = counter + 1
    IV = format(counter, 'X')
print(IV)
```

Output:

```
112233FF
```

Answer (score 0):

The function below takes a string and increases it by n from a given charset

For example, in the charset ['a','b','c'] :

- "aaa" + 1 = "aab"
- "aac" + 1 = "aba"
- "acc" + 2 = "bab"

  ```
  def str_increaser(mystr, charset, n_increase):

      # Replaces a char in given string & index
      def replace_chr_in_str(mystr, index, char):
          mystr = list(mystr)
          mystr[index] = char
          return ''.join(mystr)

      # Increases the char last (n) and possibly its left neighboor (n-1).
      def local_increase(mystr, charset):
          l_cs = len(charset)
          # increasing 1 to last char if it's not the last char in charset (e.g. 'z' in lowercase ascii).
          if (charset.index(mystr[-1]) < l_cs - 1):
              mystr = replace_chr_in_str(mystr, -1, charset[charset.index(mystr[-1]) + 1])
          # else, reset last char to the first one in charset and increase the its left char, using a reducted string for recursion
          else:
              mystr = replace_chr_in_str(mystr, -1, charset[0])
              mystr = local_increase(mystr[:-1], charset) + mystr[-1]
          return mystr

      # Case if input = "zz...zz" in an ascii lowercase charset for instance
      if (mystr == charset[-1] * len(mystr)):
          print("str_increaser(): Input already max in charset")
      else:
          for i in range(n_increase):
              mystr = local_increase(mystr, charset)

      return mystr
  ```

Here's an exemple :

```
# In bash : $ man ascii
# charset = map(chr, range(97, 123)) + map(chr, range(65, 91))
import string
charset = string.lowercase + string.uppercase
print(str_increaser("RfZ", charset, 2)) # outputs "Rgb"
```

This function might be used to get all permutations in some charsets.

Answer (score -1):

So are you literally wanting to change the last two bits of the string to "FF"? If so, easy

```
string = "11223300"
modified_string = string[:-2] + "FF"
```

**Edit from comments**

```
hex_str = "0x11223300"
for i in range(256):
    hex_int = int(hex_str, 16)
    new_int = hex_int + 0x01
    print(hex(hex_int))
    hex_str = str(hex(new_int))
```

Comment: Can you please include an example of the output that you want to achieve?